# how to slide down the div underneath the div you click on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i click on this div:

```
<div class="blog" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/template-parts/img/blog-post-img.jpeg)">
<div class="overlay">
    <h1 class="title">24-08-17 // VDM ZERO</h1>
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/template-parts/img/krul.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

i want this div to slide down underneath the other div:

```
<div class="uitgeklapt">
<h1>24-08-17 // VDM ZERO</h1>
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/template-parts/img/krul-oranje.png" alt=""/>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur blanditiis, aut beatae quaerat similique ab qui maiores molestias maxime dolorum ratione quos animi autem recusandae tempora voluptas, doloremque nemo ipsa. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi minus voluptate dolorem incidunt optio beatae dolor aut pariatur placeat eius tempora omnis, laborum, amet dolorum!</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto accusamus ad nostrum quas similique totam odit, nam, eum veritatis ut nisi, possimus laboriosam quia debitis?</p>
<div class="social-media">
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fb"></i></a>
    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
</div>
<i class="fa fa-angle-double-up arrow"></i>
```

I already have this code but when I want to repeat the same code on more places on my page all the div's slide down but I only want the div underneath the div you click on to slide down and be visible.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".uitgeklapt").hide();
});

$(".blog").click(function(){
$(".uitgeklapt").slideToggle(1000);
});

$(".arrow").click(function(){
$(".uitgeklapt").slideUp(1000);
});

</script>
```

Comment: At first glance... you haven't closed .blog and .uitgeklapt divs. Try to close them first.

Comment: Runs perfectly fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7qz3cyuw/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the div using its class it'll return every div with that class. Try using jquery's `next()` function to get the next div instead of getting it just by the class name, like this:

```
$(".blog").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".uitgeklapt").slideToggle(1000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7qz3cyuw/3/